# Delphi Pascal - Using SetFilePointerEx and GetFileSizeEx, Getting Physical Media exact size when reading as a file

Tags: delphi, api, delphi-2009, pascal

I do not know how to use any API that is not in the RTL.  I have been using SetFilePointer and GetFileSize to read a Physical Disk into a buffer and dump it to a file, something like this in a loop does the job for flash memory cards under 2GB:

```
SetFilePointer(PD,0,nil,FILE_BEGIN);
SetLength(Buffer,512);
ReadFile(PD,Buffer[0],512,BytesReturned,nil);
```

However GetFileSize has a limit at 2GB and so does SetFilePointer.  I have absolutley no idea how to delcare an external API, I have looked at the RTL and googled for many examples and have found no correct answer.

I tried this

```
function GetFileSizeEx(hFile: THandle; lpFileSizeHigh: Pointer): DWORD; 
    external 'kernel32';
```

and as suggested this

```
function GetFileSizeEx(hFile: THandle; var FileSize: Int64): DWORD;
    stdcall; external 'kernel32';
```

But the function returns a 0 even though I am using a valid disk handle which I have confirmed and dumped data from using the older API's.

I am using SetFilePointer to jump every 512 bytes and ReadFile to write into a buffer, in reverse I can use it to set when I am using WriteFile to write Initial Program Loader Code or something else to the disk.  I need to be able to set the file pointer beyond 2gb well beyond.

Can someone help me make the external declarations and a call to both GetFileSizeEx and SetFilePointerEx that work so I can modify my older code to work with say 4 to 32gb flash cards.

Comment: When `GetFileSizeEx` returns 0, the documentation advises you to call `GetLastError` to find out the reason. Did you do that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I suggest that you take a look at this [Primoz Gabrijelcic blog article](http://www.thedelphigeek.com/2007/10/case-of-mysterious-sunkoserror.html) and his [GpHugeFile](http://gp.17slon.com/gp/gphugefile.htm) unit which should give you enough pointers to get the file size.

**Edit 1** This looks rather a daft answer now in light of the edit to the question.

**Edit 2** Now that this answer has been accepted, following a long threads of comments to jachguate's answer, I feel it incumbent to summarise what has been learnt.

- [`GetFileSize`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364955%28VS.85%29.aspx) and
  [`SetFilePointer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365541%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) have no 2GB
  limitation, they can be used on files
  of essentially arbitrary size.
- [`GetFileSizeEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364957%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) and
  [`SetFilePointerEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365542%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) are much
  easier to use because they work
  directly with 64 bit quantities and
  have far simpler error condition
  signals.
- The OP did not in fact need to
  calculate the size of his disk. Since
  the OP was reading the entire
  contents of the disk the size was not
  needed.  All that was required was to
  read the contents sequentially until
  there was nothing left.
- In fact
  [`GetFileSize`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364955%28VS.85%29.aspx)/[`GetFileSizeEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364957%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)
  do not support handles to devices
  (e.g. a physical disk or volume) as
  was requested by the OP. What's more,
  [`SetFilePointer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365541%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)/[`SetFilePointerEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365542%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)
  cannot seek to the end of such device
  handles.
- In order to obtain the size of a
  disk, volume or partition, one should
  pass the the
  [`IOCTL_DISK_GET_LENGTH_INFO`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365178%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)
  control code to
  [`DeviceIoControl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365178%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).

Finally, should you need to use [`GetFileSizeEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364957%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) and [`SetFilePointerEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365542%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) then they can be declared as follows:

```
function GetFileSizeEx(hFile: THandle; var lpFileSize: Int64): BOOL;
    stdcall; external 'kernel32.dll';
function SetFilePointerEx(hFile: THandle; liDistanceToMove: Int64;
    lpNewFilePointer: PInt64; dwMoveMethod: DWORD): BOOL;
    stdcall; external 'kernel32.dll';
```

One easy way to obtain these API imports them is through the excellent [JEDI API Library](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jedi-apilib/).

Comment: I appreciate the link, I still require SetFilePointerEx to set where I am at in the file.  I am not reading the file in one pass as it would require too much memory.

Comment: I apologize for being such a pain.  About 2 years ago I wrote a peice of software that could read the boot record of a flash card so that I could inject IPL code prior to the start of the partition.  All using the non Ex versions of the API's in question.  All of this code works great.  I am currently trying to read and dump the entire physical disk to a file, which works for a 1GB stick just fine, but not an 8gb.

Comment: I fixed it so you got the rep u deserved

Comment: Thanks for the additional summary information.  Yeah to start all I needed was to dump a card to a file so I can see the entire structure.  In the end I do need to write to particular area's or even the entire disk, and to be dynamic would have to find the end to determine what to write.  But that comes later I should have concentrated on the immediate problem.

Comment: @suicide well the good news for you is that the information above shows you how to do all me that

Comment: Yeah I noticed, it all looks very good.  I appreciate it wish there was more of a way to thank people on this site but the only way of communicating seems to be commenting.  Its a lonely world for pascal programmers, especially if you happen to be mediocre like me.  All my friends are C or C++ programmers and while I am learning C++, all I can do at this point is translate code.  Embecardo has disappointed me and 2009 was the last version I probably will have ever bought.

Comment: @Suicide I'm not sure I'd be so fast to give up on Delphi. C/C++ are really much harder and less productive than Delphi. Delphi 2010 and XE have both been excellent releases. XE in particular had few new features but is much more stable than earlier versions, 2009 had quite a few problems, especially with its generics implementation.

Comment: I haven't had a problem with 2009 per say.  I also do understand how much harder it is for me personally to lose the RTL/VCL I am used to.  The failure of Kylix and the fact I cant even get 3 installed anymore and the general lack of support that has been the last 2 decades is always a part of it.  I am self taught as a programmer I just so happend to work for a company that used Delphi and I learned it on my own time.  I am looking to move on, both from delphi and windows.  Things like the Lazarus project just aren't ready yet.  Ill probably still do quick projects in 09 time to time.

Comment: Continuing, I write some public stuff for free most of my coding is for me and I would rather dump my upgrade money into other software and equipment.  It's not a career and while it can be a source of income it just isn't at the moment.  The only reason I even upgraded to 2009 was for unicode support, the pointer math was nice.  Both updates were a little late and if they want to keep their products and pascal alive, they need to keep up.  I only started Delphi because it was available to me and I was able to teach myself.  Thanks though, I appreciate your time.

Answer (score 3):

The [GetFileSizeEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364957%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) routine expects a pointer to a [LARGE_INTEGER](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383713%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) data type, and documentation says:

> If your compiler has built-in support for 64-bit integers, use the QuadPart member to store the 64-bit integer

Lucky you, Delphi has built-in support for 64 bit integers, so use it:

```
var
  DriveSize: LongWord;
begin
  GetFilePointerSizeEx(PD, @DriveSize);
end;
```

[SetFilePointerEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365542%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), on the other hand, expects parameters for liDistanceToMove, lpNewFilePointer, both 64 bit integers.  My understanding is it wants signed integers, but you have the UInt64 data type for Unsingned 64 bit integers if I'm missunderstanding the documentation.

Comment: I assume you meant GetFileSizeEx.  My problem is I can not seem to make it work.  To start its not in the RTL so i have to add the decleration in the unit I am working with.  But it seems to just plain fail after I do so.

Comment: @jach DriveSize is only 32 bits wide. Is that what you intended?

Comment: @Suicide it fails because you call it wrong. You need to use @DriveSize rather than Pointer(DriveSize).

Comment: Is that because of the pointer cast?  I dont see where I put the variable type in there.  I used an Int64 in several attempts and since no value was ever returned to it, it just had whatever random number the memory garbage had to offer.  @Second post I will try it again in about 5 minutes brb

Comment: @Suicide you should also declare the file size out parameter as a var rather than a pointer. However you can get the answer with plain old GetFileSize.

Comment: GetFileSizeEx(PD, @DriveSize);  with function GetFileSizeEx(hFile: THandle; lpFileSizeHigh: Pointer): DWORD; external 'kernel32';  I get nothing but access violations.  I HAVE eliminated all other code to make sure some new change wasnt affecting this.  I still believe I am not making a proper external decleration.

Comment: @Suicide you've missed stdcall calling convention

Comment: K i will see if I can fix that, I think maybe I need to reword my question up top.  Overall I still cant do this without the SetFilePointerEx, once i get past 2GB i wont be able to set the position.  BUT one thing at a time.

Comment: you really want it to be function GetFileSizeEx(hFile: THandle; var FileSize: Int64): DWORD;

Comment: Alright i added the stdcall, no more access violations, I will try making the next change you suggested.  My problem is at this point, if its in the RTL I can use it, if its not I have no clue at all what I am doing.  I havent coded anything in a year and almost never use a DLL outside of whatevers already defined in the RTL

Comment: @Suicide well you can do huge files with SetFilePointer but it is indeed easier with the Ex version.

Comment: In the debugger if the value of DriveSize was say 51837025451523239 then thats what it is after I try to get the size.  I changed it and it does the same thing.  I am pretty sure if i check the result it will be 0 which is fail.

Comment: I have not I was assuming since I am working with the raw data down to the boot record that the number wont match and I need an exact number, either way I still cant dump the data without the rest of my problem.  I posted my code, I think I will post a new question with one problem, 1 line of code that doesnt work.

Comment: @FileStream, I guess I can, does it work on a physical disk?  I need to be able to edit the boot record even move the partition markers etc.  I am not using an actual file i think u call it a pipe?  I must be able to use the opposit of all this and write data in the end, this is a very small part of what i need todo.

Comment: @suicide No it doesn't work with pipes and neither does GetFileSize according to the documentation! You need to slow down and go back to basics because at the moment you are missing too much knowledge to do the task effectively.

Comment: Alright well i rephrased the question. But now I guess I need to some more as well.  SetFilePointer works just fine for using ReadFile and WriteFile API's which is what I need and all I have ever needed.  I need to be able to set the pointer beyond 2GB.  SetFilePointerEx can get me the disk size by setting FILE_END and reading the returned result.

Comment: @suicide you can do it with SetFilePointer. There is no 2gb limit. Slow down and read the msdn docs carefully! But Ex will be easier. But GetFileSize can't work on pipes and you've given that one up which is good. Incidentally the return type for GetFileSizeEx is BOOL.

Comment: @suicide why do you need anything beyond Read and WriteFile anyway? Just read it from the beginning until there's none left to read.

Comment: Okay traditionally You can call SetFilePointer with FILE_END and the return value is the size of the file.  I can no longer use this.  So yes I can set the position, with no clue where I am past a certain point via that call, although I can check the last position I set.  I will try using DiskSize and hope the value is actually the one i need.  I am sorry for being such a pain

Comment: Ah, This whole time I was trying to get the size.  Yes If i do a loop until the readfile returns fail, then I will know when to stop.  Problem solved I believe.  Thank You?  lol

Comment: LOL  I fixed it, sorry... wow I havent used stack in so long I forgot my username and forgot how to use it i think

Comment: @David: I always do, but I'm not sure what you mean this time :-\

Comment: @jachgate OP originally accepted your answer based on the long comment thread, but then he changed the acceptance to my answer. So I got the rep in the end, BWUHA HA HA HA!!

Comment: @David: hahahaha... I got it, you got it. :D

Comment: Finally got the find disk length working thanks to an old friend popping up and answering my new questions.  Turned out to be a problem with the constant definition for the method.  Thanks guys I should be pretty set for a little bit.

Answer (score 2):

### Alternative coding

Suicide, first of all your approach is wrong, and because of your wrong approach you ran into some hairy problems with the way Windows handles Disk drives opened as files. In pseudo code your approach seems to be:

```
Size = GetFileSize;
for i=0 to (Size / 512) do
begin
  Seek(i * 512);
  ReadBlock;
  WriteBlockToFile;
end;
```

That's functionally correct, but there's a simpler way to do the same without actually getting the SizeOfDisk and without seeking. When reading something from a file (or a stream), the "pointer" is automatically moved with the ammount of data you just read, so you can skip the "seek". All the functions used to read data from a file return the amount of data that was actually read: you can use that to know when you reached the end of the file without knowing the size of the file to start with!

Here's an idea of how you can read an physical disk to a file, without knowing much about the disk device, using Delphi's TFileStream:

```
var DiskStream, DestinationStream:TFileStream;
    Buff:array[0..512-1] of Byte;
    BuffRead:Integer;
begin
  // Open the disk for reading
  DiskStream := TFileStream.Create('\\.\PhysicalDrive0', fmOpenRead);
  try
    // Create the file
    DestinationStream := TFileStream.Create('D:\Something.IMG', fmCreate);
    try

      // Read & write in a loop; This is where all the work's done:
      BuffRead := DiskStream.Read(Buff, SizeOf(Buff));
      while BuffRead > 0 do
      begin
        DestinationStream.Write(Buff, BuffRead);
        BuffRead := DiskStream.Read(Buff, SizeOf(Buff));
      end;

    finally DestinationStream.Free;
    end;
  finally DiskStream.Free;
  end;
end;
```

You can obviously do something similar the other way around, reading from a file and writing to disk. Before writing that code I actually attempted doing it your way (getting the file size, etc), and immediately ran into problems! Apparently Windows doesn't know the exact size of the "file", not unless you read from it.

### Problems with disks opened as files

For all my testing I used this simple code as the base:

```
var F: TFileStream;
begin
  F := TFileStream.Create('\\.\PhysicalDrive0', fmOpenRead);
  try
    // Test code goes here...
  finally F.Free;
  end;
end;
```

The first (obvious) thing to try was:

```
ShowMessage(IntToStr(DiskStream.Size));
```

That fails. In the TFileStream implementation that depends on calling FileSeek, and FileSeek can't handle files larger then 2Gb. So I gave GetFileSize a try, using this code:

```
var RetSize, UpperWord:DWORD;
RetSize := GetFileSize(F.Handle, @UpperWord);
ShowMessage(IntToStr(UpperWord) + ' / ' + IntToStr(RetSize));
```

That also fails, even those it should be perfectly capable of returning file size as an 64 bit number! Next I tried using the SetFilePointer API, because that's also supposed to handle 64bit numbers. I thought I'd simply seek to the end of the file and look at the result, using this code:

```
var RetPos, UpperWord:DWORD;
UpperWord := 0;
RetPos := SetFilePos(F.Handle, 0, @UpperWord, FILE_END);
ShowMessage(IntToStr(UpperWord) + ' / ' + IntToStr(RetPos));
```

This code also fails! And now I'm thinking, why did the first code work? Apparently reading block-by-block works just fine and Windows knows exactly when to stop reading!! So I thought maybe there's a problem with the implementation of the 64 bit file handling routines, let's try seeking to end of the file in small increments; When we get an error seeking we know we reached the end we'll stop:

```
var PrevUpWord, PrevPos: DWORD;
    UpWord, Pos: DWORD;
UpWord := 0;
Pos := SetFilePointer(F.Handle, 1024, @UpWord, FILE_CURRENT); // Advance the pointer 512 bytes from it's current position
while (UpWord <> PrevUpWord) or (Pos <> PrevPos) do
begin
  PrevUpWord := UpWord;
  PrevPos := Pos;
  UpWord := 0;
  Pos := SetFilePointer(F.Handle, 1024, @UpWord, FILE_CURRENT);
end;
```

When trying this code I had a surprise: It doesn't stop at the of the file, it just goes on and on, for ever. It never fails. To be perfectly honest I'm not sure it's supposed to ever fail... It's probably not supposed to fail. Anyway, doing a READ in that loop fails when we're past the end of file so we can use a VERY hacky mixed approach to handle this situation.

### Ready-made routines that work around the problem

Here's the ready-made routine that gets the size of the physical disk opened as a file, even when `GetFileSize` fails, and `SetFilePointer` with `FILE_END` fails. Pass it an opened TFileStream and it will return the size as an Int64:

```
function Hacky_GetStreamSize(F: TFileStream): Int64;
var Step:DWORD;

    StartPos: Int64;
    StartPos_DWORD: packed array [0..1] of DWORD absolute StartPos;

    KnownGoodPosition: Int64;
    KGP_DWORD: packed array [0..1] of DWORD absolute KnownGoodPosition;

    Dummy:DWORD;

    Block:array[0..512-1] of Byte;
begin
  // Get starting pointer position
  StartPos := 0;
  StartPos_DWORD[0] := SetFilePointer(F.Handle, 0, @StartPos_DWORD[1], FILE_CURRENT);
  try
    // Move file pointer to the first byte
    SetFilePointer(F.Handle, 0, nil, FILE_BEGIN);
    // Init
    KnownGoodPosition := 0;
    Step := 1024 * 1024 * 1024; // Initial step will be 1Gb
    while Step > 512 do
    begin
      // Try to move
      Dummy := 0;
      SetFilePointer(F.Handle, Step, @Dummy, FILE_CURRENT);
      // Test: Try to read!
      if F.Read(Block, 512) = 512 then
        begin
          // Ok! Save the last known good position
          KGP_DWORD[1] := 0;
          KGP_DWORD[0] := SetFilePointer(F.Handle, 0, @KGP_DWORD[1], FILE_CURRENT);
        end
      else
        begin
          // Read failed! Move back to the last known good position and make Step smaller
          SetFilePointer(F.Handle, KGP_DWORD[0], @KGP_DWORD[1], FILE_BEGIN);
          Step := Step div 4; // it's optimal to devide by 4
        end;
    end;
    // From here on we'll use 512 byte steps until we can't read any more
    SetFilePointer(F.Handle, KGP_DWORD[0], @KGP_DWORD[1], FILE_BEGIN);
    while F.Read(Block, 512) = 512 do
      KnownGoodPosition := KnownGoodPosition + 512;
    // Done!
    Result := KnownGoodPosition;
  finally
    // Move file pointer back to starting position
    SetFilePointer(F.Handle, StartPos_DWORD[0], @StartPos_DWORD[1], FILE_BEGIN);
  end;
end;
```

To be complete, here are two routines that may be used to set and get the file pointer using Int64 for positioning:

```
function Hacky_SetStreamPos(F: TFileStream; Pos: Int64):Int64;
var aPos:Int64;
    DWA:packed array[0..1] of DWORD absolute aPos;
const INVALID_SET_FILE_POINTER = $FFFFFFFF;
begin
  aPos := Pos;
  DWA[0] := SetFilePointer(F.Handle, DWA[0], @DWA[1], FILE_BEGIN);
  if (DWA[0] = INVALID_SET_FILE_POINTER) and (GetLastError <> NO_ERROR) then
    RaiseLastOSError;
  Result := aPos;
end;

function Hacky_GetStreamPos(F: TFileStream): Int64;
var Pos:Int64;
    DWA:packed array[0..1] of DWORD absolute Pos;
begin
  Pos := 0;
  DWA[0] := SetFilePointer(F.Handle, 0, @DWA[1], FILE_CURRENT);
  Result := Pos;
end;
```

### Last notes

The 3 routines I'm providing take as a parameter an TFileStream, because that's what I use for file reading and writing. They obviously only use TFileStream.Handle, so the parameter can simply be replaced with an file handle: the functionality would stay the same.

Comment: There's quite a bit wrong with this. First of all you make no attempt to handle errors in GetFileSize. And handling errors in GetFileSize is quite hard.  Secondly the documentation of GetFileSize makes it clear that it does not work for pipes.  Finally, your self-confessed hacky attempt to get the device size is pretty ugly - there are better ways I'm sure! Still, you get a +1 all the same.

Comment: @David, my hacky GetFileSize is not supposed to be used on Pipes; It's very, very ugly, but that's acceptable when multiple API's that are all supposed to return the "file" size fail! MSDN clearly states that SetFilePointer with 0 and FILE_END is supposed to give the file size, yet it fails! We don't even need MSDN to guess what GetFileSize is supposed to do: for me it fails.

Comment: @Cosmin it fails because it doesn't work on pipes as stated in the documentation, it works for normal files

Comment: @David, we're not dealing with pipes here. GetFileType returns FILE_TYPE_DISK for the handle returned by opening an physical disk.

Comment: @cosmin ok my terminology was wrong I was jus repeating that used by OP. What does GetLastError tell you?

Comment: The highly-informative ERROR_INVALID_FUNCTION error ("Incorrect function.") is returned for both calls to GetFileSize and calls to SetFilePointer with FILE_END. If I do the same test but open a huge VMDK file (46 Gb) I get the expected result from both GetFileSize and SetFilePointer, so it's not a problem with the call setup but a problem with the API itself. Between the test with the physical disk and the test with the huge file, the only difference was the constant I'd pass as the first parameter to TFileStream.Create

Comment: Quote from MSDN page on GetFileSize: `You cannot use the GetFileSize function with a handle of a nonseeking device such as a pipe or a communications device.` Quote from MSDN page on SetFilePointer: `The hFile parameter must refer to a file stored on a seeking device; for example, a disk volume. Calling the SetFilePointer function with a handle to a non-seeking device such as a pipe or a communications device is not supported, even though the SetFilePointer function may not return an error.`; FILE_TYPE_DISK supports seeking, and SetFilePointer works with anything but "FILE_END".

Comment: @Cosmin I think what it's telling you is that you can't use those functions on that handle. I'm sure the API functions will be working as intended.

Comment: @David, I honestly doubt the functions are behaving "as intended" and they're definitively not working as documented. If this really was Microsoft's intention I'm sure they'd have used an better error message, like ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE ("The handle is invalid.").

Comment: @Cosmin Of course they are working as intended! We just haven't found the appropriate bit of documentation yet. It's clear that we all of us in this thread don't really know what we are talking about, myself especially!!

Comment: @Cosmin see the update to my answer which I hope clarifies a few things. In particular I now believe `DeviceIoControl` to be the to find the size of a disk, volume or partition.

Comment: I appreciate your efforts to find new solutions.  I dumped way past 4gb last nite but the MS is so freaking slow I decided to stop the process before I saw if the code stopped properly or not.  My current solution for "addressing" when reading is to use File_Current and then move in 4096 4k blocks. Later when I want to write data, I will have to be able to goto a particular address though.

Answer (score 0):

I know this thread is old, but...

One small suggestion - if you use the Windows **DeviceIoControl(...)** function you can get Drive Geometry and/or Partition Information, and use them to get the total size/length of the opened drive or partition.  No more messing around with incrementally seeking to the end of the device.

Those IOCTLs can also be used to give you the correct volume sector size, and you could use that instead of defaulting to 512 everywhere.

Comment: That's true, but note the accepted answer already mentions `DeviceIoControl()`.

Comment: Also calculating the size from disk geometry is inaccurate.

Answer (score 0):

Very very useful. But I got a problem for disks greater then 4 GB.
I solved replacing:

```
   // Ok! Save the last known good position
      KGP_DWORD[1] := 0;
      KGP_DWORD[0] := SetFilePointer(F.Handle, 0, @KGP_DWORD[1], FILE_CURRENT);
```

with the following:

```
  // Ok! Save the last known good position
  KnownGoodPosition := KnownGoodPosition + Step;
```

Many thanks again...

And many thanks also to James R. Twine. I followed the advice of using IOCTL_DISK_GET_DRIVE_GEOMETRY_EX and got disk dimension with no problem and no strange workaround.
Here is the code:

```
TDISK_GEOMETRY = record
  Cylinders : Int64; //LargeInteger
  MediaType : DWORD; //MEDIA_TYPE
  TracksPerCylinder: DWORD ;
  SectorsPerTrack: DWORD ;
  BytesPerSector : DWORD ;
end;
TDISK_GEOMETRY_EX = record
  Geometry: TDISK_GEOMETRY ;
  DiskSize:  Int64; //LARGE_INTEGER ;
  Data : array[1..1000] of byte; // unknown length
end;
function get_disk_size(handle: thandle): int64;
var
  BytesReturned: DWORD;
  DISK_GEOMETRY_EX : TDISK_GEOMETRY_EX;
begin
  result := 0;
  if DeviceIOControl(handle,IOCTL_DISK_GET_DRIVE_GEOMETRY_EX,
     nil,0,@DISK_GEOMETRY_EX, sizeof(TDISK_GEOMETRY_EX),BytesReturned,nil)
  then result := DISK_GEOMETRY_EX.DiskSize;
end;
```