# How do I use CreateFile to access a physical disk?

Tags: delphi, freepascal, lazarus, fpc

I asked on the Lazarus programming forum [how to open a physical disk](http://www.lazarus.freepascal.org/index.php?topic=12230.0). I want to allow the user to select physical disks from their system when they click a "Select Disk" button. There are some examples here at Stack Overflow that are similar but not quite the same (such as [Delphi - Using DeviceIoControl passing IOCTL_DISK_GET_LENGTH_INFO to get flash media physical size (Not Partition)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4581387/delphi-using-deviceiocontrol-passing-ioctl-disk-get-length-info-to-get-flash-m)).

There are lots of C and C++ examples of using `CreateFile` ([in the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and especially [an example of calling `DeviceIoControl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363147%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)) but I can't find any for Free Pascal or Delphi and I am not good enough yet to work out how to do it.

Can anyone point me in the direction of a link that explains it or better still an actual example written in Delphi or Free Pascal? Can anyone help me understand how to use it?

Comment: Kind of duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7826683/how-to-read-raw-block-from-an-usb-storage-device-with-delphi  (Except that this one mentions USB, although USB is a non-factor here. Any disk is accessed via the same technique)

Answer (score 7):

Your C example has this code:

```
/* LPWSTR wszPath */

hDevice = CreateFileW(wszPath,          // drive to open
                      0,                // no access to the drive
                      FILE_SHARE_READ | // share mode
                      FILE_SHARE_WRITE, 
                      NULL,             // default security attributes
                      OPEN_EXISTING,    // disposition
                      0,                // file attributes
                      NULL);            // do not copy file attributes
```

Converting that function call to Delphi is just a matter of changing the syntax:

```
// wszPath: PWideChar

hDevice := CreateFileW(wszPath,
                       0,
                       FILE_SHARE_READ or
                       FILE_SHARE_WRITE,
                       nil,
                       OPEN_EXISTING,
                       0,
                       0);
```

That is, use `:=` for assignment, `or` for combining bit flags, `nil` for null pointers, and `0` for null file handles.

The function is called with this:

```
#define wszDrive L"\\\\.\\PhysicalDrive0"

DISK_GEOMETRY pdg = { 0 }; // disk drive geometry structure

bResult = GetDriveGeometry (wszDrive, &pdg);
```

Again, just change the syntax to Delphi:

```
const wszDrive = '\\.\PhysicalDrive0';

var pdg: DISK_GEOMETRY;

ZeroMemory(@pdg, SizeOf(pdg));
bResult := GetDriveGeometry(wszDrive, @pdg);
```

Delphi untyped string constants are automatically whatever type they need to be in context, so we don't need any `L` prefix like C uses. Backslashes aren't special in Delphi, so they don't need to be escaped. Delphi doesn't allow initializing local variables in the declaration, so we use `ZeroMemory` to set everything to zero. Use `@` instead of `&` to get a pointer to a variable.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the help so far. The first link re USB is useful and the converted code is equally helpful for my understanding. However, one thing I wasn't clear about in my question was that when the user of my program presses the button, I want the program to ask the operating system "What disks do you have?" so it returns a list of all the physical disks. What I don't want to have to do is hard code "\\.\PHYSICALDISKX" - I need the program to work out what disks there are so the user can then select one. From there, I can then convert that to \\.\PHYSICALDISKX, if that makes sense?

Comment: Yes, that makes sense, but that's not *at all* what you asked. Getting a list of physical disks has absolutely nothing to do with how to call CreateFile. If you can't figure out [how to get such a list](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=list+of+physical+disks), then please post a new question here on Stack Overflow.

Comment: I will look at those examples and give them a try, especially the Delphi one, though I need something that will query the attached devices regardless of whether they have been mounted or not (e.g. disk from an Apple computer attached to a Windows PC - will be there physcially on the bus, but not necessarily mounted). The dskwipe example is exactly what I need, but that is another C example. I have done as you advised and asked a more specific question how to call a list of physically attached disks using Delph\Free Pascal here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8519658/how-to-call-a-list-of-